# Sending command from Chrome Extension Pop Up to "New tab" content page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am new to chrome extensions and am still fuzzy on how the different files interact with one another. My extension displays an html file on the new tab screen. The goal is to have my setting located in the popup screen of the chrome extension. 
I am having trouble sending the command from the popup to the index.html file to display the changes.

For this example, I am trying to have a light and dark mode that changes when a toggle switch is changed in the popup box.

The point is to have the data-theme be switched from light to dark or vise versa when the button is clicked in the popup.

Any help/explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be helpful. Thank you.

index.html -relevant part atleast

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
    <head>
  <script src="../content.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Esports Dashboard",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "storage"
],

"default_icon": "favicon48.jpg",
"icons": {
      "16": "favicon16.jpg",
      "48": "favicon48.jpg"
          },

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "favicon48.jpg",
  "default_popup": "popUp.html",
  "default_title": "Esports Dashboard"
},

"chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "main/index.html"
}
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylepopup.css">
<script src="content.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="popupTitle"></div>
  <div class="popupContainer">
    <h3 class="spoilerSetting">Spoiler Default</h3>
    <form class="spoilerToggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggleSpoiler" class="checkboxSpoiler"></input>
      <label for="toggleSpoiler" class="switchSpoiler"></label>
    </form>
    <h3 class="darkModeSetting">Dark Mode</h3>
    <form class="darkModeToggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggleDarkMode" class="checkboxDarkMode"></input>
      <label for="toggleDarkMode" class="switchDarkMode"></label>
    </form>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

content.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('toggleDarkMode');
  var checkboxDarkMode = document.querySelector('input[name=theme]');

  checkboxDarkMode.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked){
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
    }
    else {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Remove "content_scripts" section entirely and rename content.js to popup.js, add index.js to index.html via the standard `<script src>` tag, remove content.js from index.html then see [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: I assume you are referring to #3 being the best solution for my case?

Comment: #1 is also fine, there's nothing wrong with the good ol' localStorage. BTW in modern browsers you can use `prefers-color-scheme` CSS instead of or in addition to manual switching.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the purpose of the popup.js file is in that example.
localStorage.sharedData = JSON.stringify({foo: 123, bar: [1, 2, 3], theme: 'light'});
Will I need to replace any of this to get it to work with my code?

Comment: popup.js is the script file of popup.html, if you need to store some data in response to user actions inside the popup.